# Is ORDER BY optimized for TOP()?

Tags: t-sql

If I write a query:

```
SELECT TOP(10) 
FROM table
ORDER BY name
```

will TSQL first take the top 10 elements, then order those, or will it ORDER BY the full table then return the top 10 of the entire table?

Comment: [Logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement)

Comment: *"will TSQL first take the top 10 elements"* also doesn't make much sense. What is the "top" of something if it doesn't have an order.

Comment: @Larnu, please write your second comment  as answer, so the OP could close the thread and other people will not waste their time in coming here (as I did now)

Comment: If there is an index with name as the first column, then it will use that and only read the first ten.  Otherwise it has to read them all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TSQL must order the elements ***then*** take the `TOP` N of those ordered elements. Ordering, to be efficient, should require an index so as to not do a full table sort. That is, with an index, the sorting doesn't happen on every query, so `TOP N` can take advantage of that fact.

Your question can be explained more visually and directly in SSMS's explain plan UI.

As to the title of your question, slightly different from the content: `ORDERBY` is not "optimized" for `TOP` per se, but it *is* a requirement. This is noted by the commenters to your question.